# Should I use gerund only in the sentence like "I postpone meeting"?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds, to-infinitive

I think the word 'postpone' is related to the future tense. But after postpone, we learned that we should use gerund only. I think that the word 'postpone' matches to-infinite.

Is it impossible to use to infinite after the word "postpone"? If there is a reason why, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The meeting might be in the future, but the act of "postponement" can be in the past.

So it is correct to say:

> Yesterday I postponed our meeting until the end of the month.

Or

> I have postponed the meeting.

In these sentences "meeting" is a noun. It's not a gerund.

---

Now you can also postpone actions.

In these cases you use the gerund, not infinitive.

> I postponed sending the letter until I could speak to you.

"Sending the letter" is a gerund phrase.

You could use an infinitive to give the purpose of the postponement.

> I postponed the meeting to give us time to cool down.

It would be incorrect to say "I postponed to send the letter".  This has a purpose, but it doesn't say what was postponed.

This is part of the grammar of the word "postpone".  Some verbs take gerunds, some take infinitives.  "Postpone" takes gerunds.

---

There is nothing about tense in the choice of infinitive or gerund.  The main verb can be in past, present or future.  But some tenses would be very rare.

> I postpone meetings  (Your job is to make meetings happen late???  Very odd!!)

> I'll postpone the meeting until next week  (good - I've decided to postpone, but I've not actually done it yet.)

> I've postponed the meeting until next week (good - here the meeting is already postponed)